# Can I change a Windows Server 2012 product key later?

Tags: windows-server-2012, product-key, windows-activation, deactivation

Suppose I have a personal key through DreamSpark, but I'm still waiting for a company key (site licence or something).  Can I install Windows Server 2012 on our dev server now with my personal key so I can start web socket development immediately, and then deactivate the key and enter a new one in a week or so?

The server's only being used by me anyway for development, and I'm just wondering if I can temporarily use my personal key until I get a company key, so that I can still use my personal key later for my own server at home.

Comment: Did the provided answer work for you? If so, please mark it accepted. Otherwise a comment explaining why it didn't help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a vbs script for 2008 servers that did this; however, there looks like a new method [(from Microsoft) here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750773/en-us) that covers windows 8 and 2012 server.

> Run the following command at an elevated command prompt:
>   Cscript.exe %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk
>
> *Note You can also use the Volume Activation Management Tool (VAMT) 3.0 to change the product key remotely, or if you want to change the product key on multiple computers.*

The instructions I used for 2008 are:

```
Open the command prompt and navigate to %windir%\System32 directory

slmgr.vbs -cpky (this clears the KMS entry you may have)
slmgr.vbs -upk (this removes any product key installed)
slmgr.vbs -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx (where the x’s are the new product key you want to use)
slmgr.vbs -ato (this activates the server)

Type slmgr.vbs for further options….
```

Comment: System and change key is also good enough.

Comment: Yeah, except the solution is for when it's not available through the GUI, hence the Microsoft KB article titled - ""Change product key" link is *not* available in Windows 8 or in Windows Server 2012"